# Raspberry Pi, USB Audio Card and 3.5mm Microphone

Tags: audio, audio-playback, usb-audio, microphone

I've been trying to use this USB Audio card: https://http2.mlstatic.com/tarjeta-de-sonido-usb-71-con-control-de-volumen-D_NQ_NP_904044-MCO31004989404_062019-F.webp as sound output and input.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2019/06/using-a-usb-audio-device-with-the-raspberry-pi/ and the output works as expected but when I try to record something using a 3.5mm microphone in the other socket, ([https://www.importacioneswest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/61jp2CwmoqL.*SL1300*-1024x1024.jpg](https://www.importacioneswest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/61jp2CwmoqL._SL1300_-1024x1024.jpg)) it only creates blank files.

Do I need to configure anything else?

I used the following command to record:

```
arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c1 -V mono test.wav
```

These are the cards the Pi recongnizes:

```
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-3f980000.usb-1.4, full spe
```

The capture devices:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And the mixer info:

```
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 151
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [42%] [-16.38dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [42%] [-16.38dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined cvolume cvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127 Capture 0 - 16
  Mono: Playback 75 [59%] [14.06dB] [off] Capture 16 [100%] [23.81dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto Gain Control',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

Comment: My old answer might help your new question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100975/ugreen-usb-soundcard-microphone-in-fail-but-speaker-out-work. Suggestion: If your mic is not "electret", try one and see if it helps.  Don't use "condenser" or "dynamic".

Comment: Please don't ask the same question two times. Instead edit your first question [Ugreen USB Soundcard - Microphone IN fail but Speaker OUT work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100975/ugreen-usb-soundcard-microphone-in-fail-but-speaker-out-work).

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't found that question. Still, that question doesn't have a good solution for the problem :/